# Flake8 D103 Missing docstring in public function for unit tests

Tags: python, lint, flake8

Flake8 is given me the `D103 Missing docstring in public function` error for my unit tests. I would not consider my unit tests public functions. I get:

```
test/base_classes/test_component.py:7:1: D103 Missing docstring in public function
test/base_classes/test_component.py:13:1: D103 Missing docstring in public function
test/base_classes/test_component.py:25:1: D103 Missing docstring in public function
test/base_classes/test_component.py:35:1: D103 Missing docstring in public function
test/base_classes/test_component.py:41:1: D103 Missing docstring in public function
```

How do I disable this check for my tests?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following to your `.flake8` file at the root of your repository to ignore all D103 errors for test code:

```
per-file-ignores =
     test/*: D103
```